# Last write time of directory or fileset in NAnt

Tags: file, directory, nant

NAnt has [directory::get-last-write-time](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/functions/directory.get-last-write-time(System.String).html) and [file::get-last-write-time](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/functions/file.get-last-write-time(System.String).html), but I am looking for a way to get the time of the most recent write of any file in a directory (recursively) or fileset.

directory::get-last-write-time might seem useful, but it only gets updated if a file directly in the directory gets written to, not for a file within a sub-directory.

Is there any way to do this with stock NAnt or would I have to write something that recurses over all the contents of a directory/fileset and finds the most recent write time?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with NAnt using a plain old `<foreach>` loop. A little bit awkward but it works:

```
<target name="go">
  <fileset
    id="paths"
    basedir="C:\foo">
    <include name="**/*" />
  </fileset>
  <!-- preset with Unix epoch -->
  <property
    name="most.recent"
    value="1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" />
  <foreach item="File" property="path">
    <in>
      <items refid="paths" />
    </in>
    <do>
      <property
        name="current"
        value="${file::get-last-write-time(path)}" />
      <property
        name="most.recent"
        value="${current}"
        if="${datetime::parse(current) > datetime::parse(most.recent)}" />
    </do>
  </foreach>
  <echo message="${most.recent}" />
</target>
```